# Windows 10: Change Volume icon not showing on taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

The change volume icon is no longer visible on my taskbar.

So, I went to settings by right clicking on the taskbar.

I tried turning on the volume icon from the *"Select which icons appear on the taskbar"* but to no use. Following is a screenshot indicating the same:

[image]

I tried doing the same from *"Turn system icons on or off"*. Here, the volume button seems to be disabled.

[image]

I'm using Windows 10 Pro. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto Yes. No change.

Comment: I have this problem on the past, but, I can resolve it always rebooting machine. Can you open start menu and search "sound"? Its a "control panel" applet (the same who you open when on taskbar right click sound icon and select devices). Here you can check if you have any problem with the installed sound car.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto Reinstalled the realtek driver. Volume icon is now visible in taskbar and the volume button is enabled on the *"Turn system icons on or off"* menu.

Comment: My volume control is always present, but only works intermittently.  Finally it stopped working altogether.  There is way too much complexity in what used to be the simplest function: volume +/-  I installed this utility and it works great for me (love the WinKey+MouseWheel to control volume): http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/3r1c-Volume-Control.shtml

Comment: Win 11 changed the taskbar completely and now requires a policy: https://superuser.com/questions/1689421/how-do-i-hide-the-volume-icon-in-windows-11