# How do I hide the volume icon in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

I am trying to hide the volume icon in Windows 11 because I use EarTrumpet as my default volume control. How do I do so in Windows 11?

Comment: The Windows 11 Sound Icon is fixed in place (Looking at my own Windows 11 system). In Windows 10 the Sound icon can be hidden.  Look in Settings, System, Sound to see if the additional devices and settings can assist you.

Comment: @John nothing is there

Comment: So you will need to live with Windows 11 the way it is. Because my comment was correct, I submitted it as an answer to assist you and others.

Answer (score 4):

The Windows 11 Taskbar has been re-written entirely (lots of articles on this) and is not modifiable in any workable way - at least as Windows 11 is now.

There may be changes down the road, but there is no concrete information on this.

The Windows 11 Sound Icon is also fixed in place (Looking at my own Windows 11 system). (In Windows 10 the Sound icon can be hidden).

There are some settings Settings, System, Sound but these are very limited.

Answer (score 3):

Run this and select "Turn System Icons On or Off"

```
shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
```

Comment: Regarding the advice for Windows 11, the answer here is a lie; there is in fact no such option as has been noted several times

Comment: Ok, so, It's not a "lie" - but it's not properly explained. If you're using the standard Windows 11 UI (i.e. taskbar), then yes, this won't help. But if you're using [ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) and activate Windows 10-style taskbar, then yes, this WILL work.

Comment: @FernandoFigueiredo I use ExplorerPatcher, but I do have it set to the Win11 taskbar, not Win10. I'm guessing it will not work for me?

Comment: @ETL probably not. I stopped using ExplorerPatcher awhile ago in favor of StartAllBack, but also, I don't think there are many reasons to use ExplorerPatcher if you'll keep using the (neutered) Win11 taskbar - I believe most of the other features in ExplorerPatcher you can get some other way without it.

Comment: Interesting. What does StartAllBack do better? The main thing I like about EP is the full-screen Win 8 style Start Menu. (The reason I'm giving the Win 11 taskbar a shot right now is that I figure it'll only become more and more standard, so I should try not to hang on to the outdated Win 10 style when it doesn't have many substantive benefits for me. I like the Win 10 flyouts for wifi, clock, etc., but setting those to Win 10 in EP also makes their responsiveness veeeeery laggy. The fact that my PC is aging doesn't help that.)

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed that setting the Group Policy setting also does NOT remove it.
Just waiting for this to start working in some future update :-)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've tried in several ways and it's really not possible to hide, but I found a palliative solution:

I use ElevenClock to have the clock on the bar of the two monitors (what it does is create an overlay on the taskbar with the clock), so I went into the ElevenClock settings and made it wider, making it overlap too the sound icon, so I only have the EarTrumpet visible on the screen
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87RHa.png)

sorry for the english, i'm using google translate